# Apply .ui-datepicker-trigger class on jquery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply css properties on date picker image. This is my code please suggestion any changes,

```
$("#StartDate").addClass('ui-datepicker-trigger').css('vertical-align', 'middle' , 'margin-bottom' , '0px');
```

My requirement is, since the css properties is not written in css class, How to run this code in IE8 ?

Answer (score 3):

You should read the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) docs. The proper way to set multiple values is this:

```
.css({
    'vertical-align': 'middle',
    'margin-bottom': '0px'
});
```